# How to Add a New StoryBoard, and set it to become the Main StoryBoard xCode without error

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Currently, I have a working app with a single storyBoard. The working app is based on master-detail view layout. I decided to add a new storyboard, and set it to become the main storyboard. When I click run, it will run and display a blank page, which is what I expected as I have not added any view controllers.

I am still new to objective-C, as such, there are many things that I still do not understand, Here comes the interesting part.

When I add a UIViewController(and associated it to a subclass of UIViewController) inside my newly changed Main storyboard, and then tried to run it, it displays an error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7569a80'
```

Under my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

return YES;
}
```

I am not so sure what do I need to add to the code above. I did try the below line without success too,

```
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

As such, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have code (maybe in the app delegate) where you use the method viewControllers (which would be valid for tab bar, split view, or navigation controllers, but not for a UIViewController)?

Comment: @rdelmar I thought about that too, but I am not sure what to add. Updated my codes above.

Answer (score 5):

Take storyboard file from `New file-->ios-->user interface---> storyboard`

create `@property` storyboard in appdelegate
like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIStoryboard* storyboard ;
```

before implementation in .m file write:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *initialViewController;
@end
```

This is to take refrence of initial viewcontroller.

then `@synthesize storyboard` in appdelegate.m
 and then for navigation you can write in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 //init storyboard
storyboard = nil;
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
{

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
       storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhoneIOS5" bundle:nil];

        NSLog(@"Version < 6");
        // iPhone Classic
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
      storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"Version 6");
    }




    //NSLog(@"IOS 6");
}
else
{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhoneIOS5" bundle:nil];
     //NSLog(@"IOS 5");
}
self.initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

//`instantiateInitialViewController` means it returns the **arrow pointed view-controller** on storyboard that is root view controller.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.initialViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I can't seem to be able to key in self.initialViewController. Did I miss out anything?

Comment: Nope. Its still gives an error at "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));"

Comment: try debuging where is exactly your problem..or try resetting simulator

Comment: The error was because of the splitview and navigation controller decleration at appdelegate, once I removed it, it works fine without the need to implement the codes above. :)

Answer (score 5):

On Xcode 7 you can go to info.plist and set the key "Main storyboard file base name" to the name of your new Storyboard .

Example: You create a new storyboard file by going to file -> new -> file -> Storyboard file and you save it as "MyAwesomeUI.storyboard" then in info.plist you change the key of "Main storyboard file base name" to "MyAwesomeUI" .

Cheers!